# How do you draw a circle?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, illustration

I'm trying to draw a circle in Adobe Illustrator, from the center of another to a point like this:

[image]

In this print-screen I've had to over extend the circle, I want it to lie on that intersection.

However when I do draw it to the point, it randomly turns into a flat line, I've no idea why!

[image]

(When I let go, it drew a line - the gif timer ran out).

Answer (score 3):

Strange! Happened for me too.

As a workaround, I would draw the circle, place the circle's center anchor at the wished location, and then resize the circle outwards to the intersection point on the right side of the diagram.

Comment: Thanks, I drew a circle at the center and used the scale tool to move it outwards to the intersection; maybe one day I'll found out why this happens.

Comment: Illustrator bugs. There are MANY!

Answer (score 3):

To draw a circle from a center point along to a vertical or Horizontal point. you have to depend on `Smart Guides`.

First you should activate the `smart guides` in Illustrator by going to `View > Smart Guides` and check it or by the shortcut <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>

Then proceed with you normal drawing and when you reach the "outsider point" or let's call it the end of the vertical or Horizontal radius of the circle. pause you cursor for a second until you can see a smart guide indicator with it Magenta color and besid it will appear a small word "anchor", then move your cursor up a little, you will notice that the smart guide will snap your cursor to the anchor you step over just like a magnet to it.

The screen capture hereunder will show you how your problem has been solved using the `Smart Guides`.

[image]